# Teradata partition on daily basis while data coming for one day

Tags: teradata

I have a big table where the partitioning is created. The partition is created on daily basis but the data is coming only for the last day of each month.

This is happening for 10-12 tables.
I want to know what can be the downsides of it.

will it occupy more space? and how will it react to retrieving of records.

Thanks,
Sumit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no overhead for empty partitions and if you collect stats regularly there should be no downside. Of course you should write matching WHERE-conditons, if you do something like `BETWEEN 2016-01-01 and 2016-08-01` the optimizer still needs to consider all partitions (even if the stats tell most are empty) and might do a different join type.

But IMHO you might better consider monthly partitions instead to avoid all those unused partitions and keep the partition count low. Then it doesn't matter how you write your condition, too.

Comment: Great Dnoeth, 
That's what i thought of.
Thanks a lot!!